# Object property stored as string in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I am working on code from a fellow coder. All credit goes to him https://github.com/edzh/carabao, however I am trying to repurpose the code to integrate new rules, and the following has hung me up.

```
export interface Player {
  name: string;
  cards: string[];
  pass: boolean;
  score: number;
  connected: boolean;
}
```

```
export interface GameState {
  id: string;
  gameName: string;
  players: { [clientId: string]: Player };
  host: string;
  spectators: { [clientId: string]: Player };
  spectatorIds: string[];
  clientIds: string[];
  startGame: boolean;
  currentPlayer: string;
  lastPlayed: {
    player: string;
    cards: string[];
  };
  playHistory: {
    player: string;
    cards: string[];
  }[];
  options: Options;
}
```

the `games[gameId].players` will initialize as something like this
`{   CZrXqGVhN: { name: 'dfgdfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true },  }`
as they are the first played to join and is done through this

```
players: {
        [clientId]: {
          name: name,
          cards: [],
          pass: false,
          score: 0,
          connected: true,
        },
```

Here I am trying to append a joining player

```
const newPlayers = games[gameId].players
    newPlayers[clientId] = {
      name: name,
      cards: [],
      pass: false,
      score: 0,
      connected: true,
    }
```

```
games[gameId].players = newPlayers
```

but when i add `newPlayers` to the `games[gameId].players` it appends as

```
  CZrXqGVhN: { name: 'dfgdfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true },
  'YHG-KuXCt': { name: 'dfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true }
 }
```

Why would this be, I have tried a couple of other methods such as assigning but they do not work either. What would cause this and is there a way to access the property as a string regardless. Sorry if this is a nearsighted question, I just learned typescript very recently.

Comment: please explain problem.

Comment: The question is indeed very unclear.

Comment: When I am trying to dynamically add an object as a property to an object, it is being added as a trying like this 
{  CZrXqGVhN: { name: 'dfgdfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true },
  'YHG-KuXCt': { name: 'dfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true }
 }

Comment: Maybe id is in String. That is why it is taking it as String

Comment: Is it the single quotes that are bothering you? Still don't see the problem...

Comment: clientId is a string in this case

Comment: it is inaccessible due to it not being added as an object.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that object. You'll need to edit your question and add what you perceive to be the problem, because I'm not seeing it. My best guess is that it's the single quotes around the second key that are throwing you off.

Comment: if add `var t  ={ CZrXqGVhN: { name: 'dfgdfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true }, 'YHG-KuXCt': { name: 'dfg', cards: [], pass: false, score: 0, connected: true } }` and  `Object.keys(t)` .a result is `(2) ["CZrXqGVhN", "YHG-KuXCt"]` and not problem

Comment: Is your concern that `CZrXqGVhN` doesn't look like a "string" but `'YHG-KuXCt'` looks different/like a string? There is no problem there, both field IDs are actually strings and JS doesn't care.